# cannot implicitlyconvert type<SubMenu> to SubMenu

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to select all the records by ContentTypeID

this is the code I'm trying to use

```
public ActionResult LoadData(int contentTypeId)
    {
        List<ProductContent> productContentList = (from pc in db.ProductContents
                                                   where pc.ContentTypeID == contentTypeId
                                                   select pc).ToList();
        ViewBag.ProductContents = productContentList;


        SubMenu subMenu = (from sm in db.SubMenuList
                                 where sm.ContentTypeID == contentTypeId
                                 select sm);

        SubMenuItem subMenuItemList = (from smi in db.SubMenuItems
                                       where smi.ContentTypeID == contentTypeId
                                       select smi);
```

Comment: you are trying to assign `IEnumerable` to a different type variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `db.SubMenuList` is a collection of `SubMenu`, then when you do this:

```
from sm in db.SubMenuList
     where sm.ContentTypeID == contentTypeId
     select sm
```

You are not selecting a single record (even if there is only one `SubMenu` with `ContentTypeID == contentTypeId`), you are selecting a *collection* of all items that match the predicate. It might be a collection with just a single item. It might be that it can only ever be a collection with a single item, but the compiler doesn't know that and isn't going to assume it.

If there is only ever one match then something like:

```
    SubMenu subMenu = (from sm in db.SubMenuList
                             where sm.ContentTypeID == contentTypeId
                             select sm).First();
```

Should work. Or, if the item might be missing then:

```
    SubMenu subMenu = (from sm in db.SubMenuList
                             where sm.ContentTypeID == contentTypeId
                             select sm).FirstOrDefault();
```

Which will set `subMenu` to `null` if no items match your condition.